# How old do I have to be to be a Minecraft marketplace creator

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to apply to become a marketplace creator but can’t find a age requirement anywhere. Does anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 2):

### Minecraft Marketplace

As far as I know there is currently no age requirement. If you are intrested, the Minecraft Marketplace FAQ can be accessed [here](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360035347351-Marketplace-FAQs).

Hope this helps!